# How to use SSL certificate in Spring boot(backend) + React.js(front-end) Application

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, ssl

My Spring boot(backend) application is running on server.port=8080
and front-end React application is running on PORT=80
I install my paid SSL .crt and .key file in httpd on CentOS server
but I couldn't run my application in https but its running in http

Answer (score 1):

Since you have configured the SSL for HTTPD, you can setup a proxy_pass to your spring boot application in configuration of httpd. If you want to use nginx as http server, you need to add one more location object in the configuration as below

```
location /springbootapp/ {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        }
```

you will need to you the string defined as location ( '/springbootapp/') in your react app as backend url.